# How can I parse or interpret the arguments given into console.log()

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(0..V); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(0..VII); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

I gotta implement such a behaviour for the console.log function. How can I interpret the arguments devided by `..`

Comment: please share your implementation.

Comment: `console.log(0..V)` is not valid javascript, you will get an undefined as you are trying to find the `V` property on the number `0.` ...do you mean `console.log('0..V')`?

Comment: that's the thing =)
I specifically need to implement exactly this behaviour, pass arguments as in the given example

Comment: you need a preprocessor and interpret the given code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which does something similar to this:

```js
const V = 5;
const VII = 7;

function getNumbers(from, to) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = from; i < to; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getNumbers(0, V));
console.log(getNumbers(0, VII));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) for [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) as prototype for `Number` with a numerical value.

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
};

console.log(...10);
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Number.prototype.__defineGetter__('X', ()=> {console.log(...arr)})
console.log(1..X)
```

`

So far I came up with that implementation, thank you everyone for hel